# Why is shader always an extra file when compile OpenGL program?

Tags: opengl, graphics

Why don't we just let main file and shader file code together?

Why we have to seperate them?

Is there any reasons that we should do so?

To make program run faster or any other reasons?

Answer (score 2):

The problem exists on multiple levels.

- **No consistent bytecode format for OpenGL:** Simply put, there's no guarantee that if the compiled bytecode for the shader is created on one computer, that same compiled form will work on another computer, even if they have the same GPU. *There's also no guarantee that the bytecode will work on the same computer with the same GPU, due to Driver updates and other hardware changes!* This is the problem that Vulkan sought to fix by introducing SPIR-V, which is supposed to work for any complying implementation of Vulkan. But OpenGL has no equivalent to SPIR-V.

  *Edit:* An extension was introduced to OpenGL to support SPIR-V. But it's not core yet, and still has the other two problems enumerated in this post.
- **No "File Literals" in most programming languages:** One could theoretically compile the String-literal source code into the program, which would at least solve the problem of having to ship multiple files at release. But most programming languages don't support this natively. C++ has proposals for so-called "File Literals" which would allow the contents of a file to be stored at compile-time as a String Literal, but as of right now (2016-09-14) that isn't official or well-supported.
- **String Literals are difficult to debug:** There's nothing stopping you from simply defining any shader you want to use directly in the source code as a large String object, whatever the representation is in your programming language. But it's difficult to debug, and cannot be modified/validated by external tools or programs (like a GLSL validator or a program which "builds" GLSL shaders based on inputs provided to it", which are often essential for professional programmers.

Lots of programmers find workarounds and solutions to these problems. In professional settings, shader source code is often compressed and stored in resource files, the same way that models, textures, sounds, etc. would be stored. So a lot of the time this problem is minimized or abstracted away.

But in a general sense, there are very few *practical*, *general-purpose* solutions to this problem.

Comment: OpenGL recently got support for SPIR-V too with the GL_ARB_gl_spirv extension.The glslang reference compiler also supports OpenGL semantics for SPIR-V. Though hardware and driver support is pretty limited now but hopefully picks up over time.

Answer (score 1):

> Why don't we just let main file and shader file code together?

What's a "main" file and what's the "shader" files?

> Why we have to seperate them?

We don't have to. It's perfectly possible to bake the shader source string into the executable. It's also perfectly possible that GLSL shader code is generated at runtime (a couple of the libraries / middleware I developed do this)

> Is there any reasons that we should do so?

Mostly for the sake of convenience. A separate file is easier to modify or update. Heck you can even add a file system monitor on it to get informed if it changes and recompile the shader when it does. This dramatically shortens development cycles.

> To make program run faster or any other reasons?

It's just a matter of convenience, actually. OpenGL doesn't care about it. All OpenGL wants to see is some valid GLSL shader source code, and it's a happy camper.

Comment: Main file is like xxx.cpp and shader file is like xxx.fragmentshader and xxx.vertexshader. I find the code in xxx.fragmentshader and xxx.vertexshader are both C++ code, so I wonder why don't we just put them in main file. This is my question.

Comment: @MarsLee: Because shader files are **not** C nor C++ code. It's an entirely different language, called "GLSL", that strongly resembles C or C++, but it is not. It's a completely different language. Also the C/C++ gets compiled into native machine code for the CPU (ARM, x86, PowerPC, or whatever the architecture is). GPUs are an entirely different architecture and a compiler for the CPU does not emit GPU code.

Comment: @MarsLee: Oh and BTW, even *if* shader code was something the compiler would understand, it still makes no sense to amalgamate everything into a single file. In fact you should try to split your program into as many different source files as possible, using `static` scope to "hide" internals from each other.